# What does it mean when doing npm install displays nothing in the console?

Tags: node.js, npm

What does it mean when doing **"npm install"** displays nothing in the console? Ie. there is no success of failure messages are displayed. It just returns back to a cursor.

Eg:

[image]

Does this mean that

- It has successfully installed everything?
- Nothing was installed because everything is already there?
- Something strange has happened?

Comment: I vote for "Something strange has happened " :)

Comment: Try `npm install --verbose`

Comment: have you tried to delete /node_modules/?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was installed because everything is already there

Answer (score 0):

You have your package.json file configured and you have a README.md file but package.json does not contain any dependency. so nothing to do and nothing to display.